# Symfony2 routing - characters size in URL

Tags: symfony, routes

Got an issue with character size in url.
Example, I have a route path:

```
_product:
pattern:  /product
defaults: { _controller: StoreBundle:Product:index }
```

and then when im using it in url(/app_dev.php/product), it works fine, but if I use same path but with some upper characters(/app_dev.php/ProduCT) then symfony says me "No route found".

Is there any way to make url immune for character size?

Comment: Of course it's case sensitive; whatever you define in your routing should match

Comment: Resolved issue with using mod_rewrite to change url case to lower

Answer (score 0):

If you NEED to do this for some reason (though, it's bad practice and is highlighting that you're doing something very wrong, then this will work:

```
_product:
    pattern:   /{url}/
    defaults:  { _controller: StoreBundle:Product:index }
    requirements:
        url:  (?i:product)
```

Essentially, you do a case insensitive regular expression with a variable in the URL. You can define multiple routes that follow a similar pattern too.

Advantage of this method is that you don't have to add rewrite rules for it.

I must reiterate though, you should not need to be doing this. It's very bad practice. It's bad for SEO for a start.

Also, it's worth noting, the term you're looking for is "case-insensitive". The characters are not changing size, they are changing case. ;)

Comment: By bad practice you mean using rewrite rules or that example u gave me?

Comment: If you have to do this, rewrite rules are a good way - but they're more complex compared to this, and harder to update depending on your server configuration. Neither this suggestion, or rewrite rules should NEED to happen though, imo - and that's what I meant.